# BCM4331 Ubuntu 14.04 Wifi <5Mbps should be >200

Tags: 14.04, wireless

Dual booted mac mini and ubuntu, osx getting speeds of over 200Mbps reported by speedtest.net. When the test doesnt timeout on the ubuntu side, I get less than 5Mbps.

Sometimes I cant even get an SSH connection to the box.

Interestingly enough, it also doesnt see any of my 5Ghz networks either.

FutureHax is the network im attempting to connect to.

```
########## wireless info START ##########

Report from: 15 Feb 2016 00:52 EST -0500

Booted last: 15 Feb 2016 00:44 EST -0500

Script from: 27 Sep 2015 00:34 UTC +0000

##### release ###########################

Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS
Release:    14.04
Codename:   trusty

##### kernel ############################

Linux 3.19.0-49-generic #55~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jan 22 11:24:31 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

\boot\vmlinuz-3.19.0-49-generic.efi.signed, ro, quiet, splash, vt.handoff=7, initrd=boot\initrd.img-3.19.0-49-generic

##### desktop ###########################

sed: can't read /home/futurehax/.dmrc: No such file or directory

Could not be determined.

##### lspci #############################

02:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Broadcom Corporation NetXtreme BCM57765 Gigabit Ethernet PCIe [14e4:16b4] (rev 10)
    Subsystem: Broadcom Corporation NetXtreme BCM57765 Gigabit Ethernet PCIe [14e4:16b4]
    Kernel driver in use: tg3

03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM4331 802.11a/b/g/n [14e4:4331] (rev 02)
    Subsystem: Apple Inc. AirPort Extreme [106b:00e4]
    Kernel driver in use: bcma-pci-bridge

##### lsusb #############################

Bus 002 Device 005: ID 046d:c534 Logitech, Inc. 
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 0bc2:331a Seagate RSS LLC 
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 05ac:8242 Apple, Inc. Built-in IR Receiver
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 0424:2513 Standard Microsystems Corp. 2.0 Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 04e8:61c3 Samsung Electronics Co., Ltd 
Bus 001 Device 007: ID 05ac:8281 Apple, Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0a5c:4500 Broadcom Corp. BCM2046B1 USB 2.0 Hub (part of BCM2046 Bluetooth)
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0424:2513 Standard Microsystems Corp. 2.0 Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub

##### PCMCIA card info ##################

##### rfkill ############################

0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no

##### lsmod #############################

b43                   421888  0 
mac80211              712704  1 b43
cfg80211              524288  2 b43,mac80211
ssb                    65536  1 b43
bcma                   53248  1 b43

##### interfaces ########################

auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

##### ifconfig ##########################

docker0   Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr <MAC 'docker0' [IF]>  
          inet addr:172.17.0.1  Bcast:0.0.0.0  Mask:255.255.0.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::<IP6 'docker0' [IF]>/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:92092 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:146569 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:5240274 (5.2 MB)  TX bytes:219047603 (219.0 MB)

eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr <MAC 'eth0' [IF]>  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
          Interrupt:16 

veth256bd9a Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr <MAC 'veth256bd9a' [IF]>  
          inet6 addr: fe80::<IP6 'veth256bd9a' [IF]>/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:78 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:156 errors:0 dropped:1 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:6396 (6.3 KB)  TX bytes:20237 (20.2 KB)

veth6dd5713 Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr <MAC 'veth6dd5713' [IF]>  
          inet6 addr: fe80::<IP6 'veth6dd5713' [IF]>/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:2110 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:2603 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:154972 (154.9 KB)  TX bytes:2673980 (2.6 MB)

veth8c6aa4b Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr <MAC 'veth8c6aa4b' [IF]>  
          inet6 addr: fe80::<IP6 'veth8c6aa4b' [IF]>/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:8 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:192 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:648 (648.0 B)  TX bytes:20935 (20.9 KB)

veth90b9f85 Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr <MAC 'veth90b9f85' [IF]>  
          inet6 addr: fe80::<IP6 'veth90b9f85' [IF]>/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:8 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:172 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:648 (648.0 B)  TX bytes:18783 (18.7 KB)

vetha5d3954 Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr <MAC 'vetha5d3954' [IF]>  
          inet6 addr: fe80::<IP6 'vetha5d3954' [IF]>/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:8 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:190 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:648 (648.0 B)  TX bytes:20755 (20.7 KB)

vethe4d6415 Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr <MAC 'vethe4d6415' [IF]>  
          inet6 addr: fe80::<IP6 'vethe4d6415' [IF]>/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:89880 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:144290 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:6366250 (6.3 MB)  TX bytes:216406793 (216.4 MB)

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr <MAC 'wlan0' [IF]>  
          inet addr:192.168.1.134  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::<IP6 'wlan0' [IF]>/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:163609 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:104454 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:235577751 (235.5 MB)  TX bytes:10873553 (10.8 MB)

##### iwconfig ##########################

vetha5d3954  no wireless extensions.

eth0      no wireless extensions.

vethe4d6415  no wireless extensions.

docker0   no wireless extensions.

veth256bd9a  no wireless extensions.

veth6dd5713  no wireless extensions.

lo        no wireless extensions.

veth90b9f85  no wireless extensions.

veth8c6aa4b  no wireless extensions.

wlan0     IEEE 802.11bg  ESSID:"FutureHax"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.462 GHz  Access Point: <MAC 'FutureHax' [AC5]>   
          Bit Rate=11 Mb/s   Tx-Power=20 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
          Link Quality=56/70  Signal level=-54 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:519  Invalid misc:444   Missed beacon:0

##### route #############################

Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 wlan0
172.17.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 docker0
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     9      0        0 wlan0

##### resolv.conf #######################

nameserver 127.0.1.1
search cfl.rr.com

##### network managers ##################

Installed:

    NetworkManager

Running:

root      1148     1  0 00:44 ?        00:00:01 NetworkManager

##### NetworkManager info ###############

NetworkManager Tool

State: connected (global)

- Device: wlan0  [FutureHax] ---------------------------------------------------
  Type:              802.11 WiFi
  Driver:            b43
  State:             connected
  Default:           yes
  HW Address:        <MAC 'wlan0' [IF]>

  Capabilities:
    Speed:           11 Mb/s

  Wireless Properties
    WEP Encryption:  yes
    WPA Encryption:  yes
    WPA2 Encryption: yes

  Wireless Access Points (* = current AP)
    PS4-A9DC9142ED84:Infra, <MAC 'PS4-A9DC9142ED84' [AC2]>, Freq 2437 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 62 WPA2
    ATT64NqD3u:      Infra, <MAC 'ATT64NqD3u' [AC1]>, Freq 2412 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 49 WPA2
    You're Too Slow: Infra, <MAC 'You're Too Slow' [AC7]>, Freq 2437 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 25 WPA2
    ATT72493RG:      Infra, <MAC 'ATT72493RG' [AC6]>, Freq 2462 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 57 WPA2
    *FutureHax:      Infra, <MAC 'FutureHax' [AC5]>, Freq 2462 MHz, Rate 11 Mb/s, Strength 66 WPA2

  IPv4 Settings:
    Address:         192.168.1.134
    Prefix:          24 (255.255.255.0)
    Gateway:         192.168.1.1

    DNS:             192.168.1.1

- Device: eth0 -----------------------------------------------------------------
  Type:              Wired
  Driver:            tg3
  State:             unavailable
  Default:           no
  HW Address:        <MAC 'eth0' [IF]>

  Capabilities:
    Carrier Detect:  yes

  Wired Properties
    Carrier:         off

##### NetworkManager.state ##############

[main]
NetworkingEnabled=true
WirelessEnabled=true
WWANEnabled=true
WimaxEnabled=true

##### NetworkManager.conf ###############

[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile,ofono
dns=dnsmasq

[ifupdown]
managed=false

##### NetworkManager profiles ###########

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/FutureHax_5Ghz]] (600 root)
[connection] id=FutureHax_5Ghz | type=802-11-wireless
[802-11-wireless] ssid=FutureHax_5Ghz | mac-address=<MAC 'wlan0' [IF]>
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/FutureHax]] (600 root)
[connection] id=FutureHax | type=802-11-wireless
[802-11-wireless] ssid=FutureHax | mac-address=<MAC 'wlan0' [IF]>
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

##### iw reg get ########################

Region: America/New_York (based on set time zone)

country 00:
    (2402 - 2472 @ 40), (3, 20)
    (2457 - 2482 @ 40), (3, 20), PASSIVE-SCAN, NO-IBSS
    (2474 - 2494 @ 20), (3, 20), NO-OFDM, PASSIVE-SCAN, NO-IBSS
    (5170 - 5250 @ 40), (3, 20), PASSIVE-SCAN, NO-IBSS
    (5735 - 5835 @ 40), (3, 20), PASSIVE-SCAN, NO-IBSS

##### iwlist channels ###################

vetha5d3954  no frequency information.

eth0      no frequency information.

vethe4d6415  no frequency information.

docker0   no frequency information.

veth256bd9a  no frequency information.

veth6dd5713  no frequency information.

lo        no frequency information.

veth90b9f85  no frequency information.

veth8c6aa4b  no frequency information.

wlan0     14 channels in total; available frequencies :
          Channel 01 : 2.412 GHz
          Channel 02 : 2.417 GHz
          Channel 03 : 2.422 GHz
          Channel 04 : 2.427 GHz
          Channel 05 : 2.432 GHz
          Channel 06 : 2.437 GHz
          Channel 07 : 2.442 GHz
          Channel 08 : 2.447 GHz
          Channel 09 : 2.452 GHz
          Channel 10 : 2.457 GHz
          Channel 11 : 2.462 GHz
          Channel 12 : 2.467 GHz
          Channel 13 : 2.472 GHz
          Channel 14 : 2.484 GHz
          Current Frequency:2.462 GHz (Channel 11)

##### iwlist scan #######################

vetha5d3954  Interface doesn't support scanning.

eth0      Interface doesn't support scanning.

vethe4d6415  Interface doesn't support scanning.

docker0   Interface doesn't support scanning.

veth256bd9a  Interface doesn't support scanning.

veth6dd5713  Interface doesn't support scanning.

lo        Interface doesn't support scanning.

veth90b9f85  Interface doesn't support scanning.

veth8c6aa4b  Interface doesn't support scanning.

Channel occupancy:

      1   APs on   Frequency:2.412 GHz (Channel 1)
      2   APs on   Frequency:2.437 GHz (Channel 6)
      4   APs on   Frequency:2.462 GHz (Channel 11)

wlan0     Scan completed :
          Cell 01 - Address: <MAC 'ATT64NqD3u' [AC1]>
                    Channel:1
                    Frequency:2.412 GHz (Channel 1)
                    Quality=38/70  Signal level=-72 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"ATT64NqD3u"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s
                              24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:6 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=000000036f1b228e
                    Extra: Last beacon: 4988ms ago
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : CCMP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
          Cell 02 - Address: <MAC 'PS4-A9DC9142ED84' [AC2]>
                    Channel:6
                    Frequency:2.437 GHz (Channel 6)
                    Quality=44/70  Signal level=-66 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"PS4-A9DC9142ED84"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 6 Mb/s
                              9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=00000010836c376b
                    Extra: Last beacon: 2988ms ago
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : CCMP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
          Cell 03 - Address: <MAC '' [AC3]>
                    Channel:11
                    Frequency:2.462 GHz (Channel 11)
                    Quality=49/70  Signal level=-61 dBm  
                    Encryption key:off
                    ESSID:""
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 6 Mb/s
                              9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=000000f61d26c205
                    Extra: Last beacon: 128ms ago
          Cell 04 - Address: <MAC '' [AC4]>
                    Channel:11
                    Frequency:2.462 GHz (Channel 11)
                    Quality=51/70  Signal level=-59 dBm  
                    Encryption key:off
                    ESSID:""
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 6 Mb/s
                              9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=000000f61d26c97a
                    Extra: Last beacon: 60ms ago
          Cell 05 - Address: <MAC 'FutureHax' [AC5]>
                    Channel:11
                    Frequency:2.462 GHz (Channel 11)
                    Quality=60/70  Signal level=-50 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"FutureHax"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=000000f61d12f1d0
                    Extra: Last beacon: 84ms ago
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : CCMP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
          Cell 06 - Address: <MAC 'ATT72493RG' [AC6]>
                    Channel:11
                    Frequency:2.462 GHz (Channel 11)
                    Quality=42/70  Signal level=-68 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"ATT72493RG"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s
                              24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:6 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=00000002208570b4
                    Extra: Last beacon: 296ms ago
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : CCMP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
          Cell 07 - Address: <MAC 'You're Too Slow' [AC7]>
                    Channel:6
                    Frequency:2.437 GHz (Channel 6)
                    Quality=27/70  Signal level=-83 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"You're Too Slow"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s
                              18 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:6 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 24 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=0000027d8e1c813b
                    Extra: Last beacon: 3408ms ago
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : CCMP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK

##### module infos ######################

[b43]
filename:       /lib/modules/3.19.0-49-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/b43/b43.ko
firmware:       b43/ucode9.fw
firmware:       b43/ucode5.fw
firmware:       b43/ucode16_mimo.fw
firmware:       b43/ucode15.fw
firmware:       b43/ucode14.fw
firmware:       b43/ucode13.fw
firmware:       b43/ucode11.fw
license:        GPL
author:         Rafał Miłecki
author:         Gábor Stefanik
author:         Michael Buesch
author:         Stefano Brivio
author:         Martin Langer
description:    Broadcom B43 wireless driver
srcversion:     11BDA0A580599B083FE4F2B
depends:        bcma,ssb,mac80211,cfg80211
intree:         Y
vermagic:       3.19.0-49-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
signer:         Magrathea: Glacier signing key
sig_key:        A9:32:DC:23:78:95:A4:4D:39:59:BF:91:A3:56:6A:20:EE:21:1F:37
sig_hashalgo:   sha512
parm:           bad_frames_preempt:enable(1) / disable(0) Bad Frames Preemption (int)
parm:           fwpostfix:Postfix for the .fw files to load. (string)
parm:           hwpctl:Enable hardware-side power control (default off) (int)
parm:           nohwcrypt:Disable hardware encryption. (int)
parm:           hwtkip:Enable hardware tkip. (int)
parm:           qos:Enable QOS support (default on) (int)
parm:           btcoex:Enable Bluetooth coexistence (default on) (int)
parm:           verbose:Log message verbosity: 0=error, 1=warn, 2=info(default), 3=debug (int)
parm:           pio:Use PIO accesses by default: 0=DMA, 1=PIO (int)
parm:           allhwsupport:Enable support for all hardware (even it if overlaps with the brcmsmac driver) (int)

[mac80211]
filename:       /lib/modules/3.19.0-49-generic/kernel/net/mac80211/mac80211.ko
license:        GPL
description:    IEEE 802.11 subsystem
srcversion:     1261743510839D352D1D895
depends:        cfg80211
intree:         Y
vermagic:       3.19.0-49-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
signer:         Magrathea: Glacier signing key
sig_key:        A9:32:DC:23:78:95:A4:4D:39:59:BF:91:A3:56:6A:20:EE:21:1F:37
sig_hashalgo:   sha512
parm:           minstrel_vht_only:Use only VHT rates when VHT is supported by sta. (bool)
parm:           max_nullfunc_tries:Maximum nullfunc tx tries before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           max_probe_tries:Maximum probe tries before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           beacon_loss_count:Number of beacon intervals before we decide beacon was lost. (int)
parm:           probe_wait_ms:Maximum time(ms) to wait for probe response before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           ieee80211_default_rc_algo:Default rate control algorithm for mac80211 to use (charp)

[cfg80211]
filename:       /lib/modules/3.19.0-49-generic/kernel/net/wireless/cfg80211.ko
description:    wireless configuration support
license:        GPL
author:         Johannes Berg
srcversion:     EF182B558008C23DD85EF03
depends:        
intree:         Y
vermagic:       3.19.0-49-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
signer:         Magrathea: Glacier signing key
sig_key:        A9:32:DC:23:78:95:A4:4D:39:59:BF:91:A3:56:6A:20:EE:21:1F:37
sig_hashalgo:   sha512
parm:           ieee80211_regdom:IEEE 802.11 regulatory domain code (charp)
parm:           cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz:Disable 40MHz support in the 2.4GHz band (bool)

[ssb]
filename:       /lib/modules/3.19.0-49-generic/kernel/drivers/ssb/ssb.ko
license:        GPL
description:    Sonics Silicon Backplane driver
srcversion:     551AE4C23939F7FBED9DA61
depends:        
intree:         Y
vermagic:       3.19.0-49-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
signer:         Magrathea: Glacier signing key
sig_key:        A9:32:DC:23:78:95:A4:4D:39:59:BF:91:A3:56:6A:20:EE:21:1F:37
sig_hashalgo:   sha512

[bcma]
filename:       /lib/modules/3.19.0-49-generic/kernel/drivers/bcma/bcma.ko
license:        GPL
description:    Broadcom's specific AMBA driver
srcversion:     F17244FFF75F9BDF92327ED
depends:        
intree:         Y
vermagic:       3.19.0-49-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
signer:         Magrathea: Glacier signing key
sig_key:        A9:32:DC:23:78:95:A4:4D:39:59:BF:91:A3:56:6A:20:EE:21:1F:37
sig_hashalgo:   sha512

##### module parameters #################

[b43]
allhwsupport: 0
bad_frames_preempt: 0
btcoex: 1
hwpctl: 0
hwtkip: 0
nohwcrypt: 0
pio: 0
qos: 1
verbose: 2

[mac80211]
beacon_loss_count: 7
ieee80211_default_rc_algo: minstrel_ht
max_nullfunc_tries: 2
max_probe_tries: 5
minstrel_vht_only: Y
probe_wait_ms: 500

[cfg80211]
cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz: N
ieee80211_regdom: 00

##### /etc/modules ######################

lp
rtc

##### modprobe options ##################

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-ath_pci.conf]
blacklist ath_pci

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf]
blacklist evbug
blacklist usbmouse
blacklist usbkbd
blacklist eepro100
blacklist de4x5
blacklist eth1394
blacklist snd_intel8x0m
blacklist snd_aw2
blacklist i2c_i801
blacklist prism54
blacklist bcm43xx
blacklist garmin_gps
blacklist asus_acpi
blacklist snd_pcsp
blacklist pcspkr
blacklist amd76x_edac

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-rare-network.conf]
alias net-pf-3 off
alias net-pf-6 off
alias net-pf-9 off
alias net-pf-11 off
alias net-pf-12 off
alias net-pf-19 off
alias net-pf-21 off
alias net-pf-36 off

[/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf]
remove iwlwifi \
(/sbin/lsmod | grep -o -e ^iwlmvm -e ^iwldvm -e ^iwlwifi | xargs /sbin/rmmod) \
&& /sbin/modprobe -r mac80211

[/etc/modprobe.d/mlx4.conf]
softdep mlx4_core post: mlx4_en

##### rc.local ##########################

exit 0

##### pm-utils ##########################

[/etc/pm/config.d/default] (644 root)
SUSPEND_MODULES="b43 bcma"

##### udev rules ########################

[/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules]
# PCI device 0x14e4:0x16b4 (tg3)
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="<MAC 'eth0' [IF]>", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="eth*", NAME="eth0"
# PCI device 0x14e4:0x4331 (b43)
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="<MAC 'wlan0' [IF]>", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="wlan*", NAME="wlan0"

########## wireless info END ############
```

Comment: Have you tried a different driver? Sometimes the b43 is not the best choice. I guess you have the newest firmware extracted?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Installing Broadcom Wireless Drivers](http://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/installing-broadcom-wireless-drivers)

Comment: Not quite. I have them installed and working, they just arent working optimally.

Answer (score 0):

It actually ended up being unrelated to my computer.

`Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s` tipped me off. My network should support over 200 Mbps. I remembered that I had to set by 2.4Ghz band to "B" only for some other device of mine and it was killing the speeds. Im still only able to get around 55Mbps, but from what I hear I think thats the best that Im going to get with the BCM4331 driver.

Comment: You need to install `firmware-b43-installer`.

Comment: Had that installed, and the firmware cutter. My machine was unable to pickup any 5ghz networks still.

Comment: I suggest another driver in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I found that the later versions of Broadcom proprietary drivers support that chip and it is tested to be working.

Run in terminal

```
sudo apt-get install bcmwl-kernel-source
```

and reboot.